# Parsing Facebook graph API JSON to html

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, facebook-graph-api

I'm new to JSON and am trying to return a list of my Facebook albums:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON("https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?fields=id,name&access_token=MY TOKEN", function (data) {
        var items = [];
        $.each(data, function (key, val) {
            items.push("<li id='" + key + "'>" + val + "</li>");
        });

        $("<ul/>", {
            "class": "my-new-list",
            html: items.join("")
        }).appendTo(".results");
    });
});
```

JSON from Facebook:

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "id": "10150589771916817",
         "name": "Mobile Uploads",
         "created_time": "2012-03-03T14:47:48+0000"
      },
      {
         "id": "41633726816",
         "name": "Old pics",
         "created_time": "2008-08-18T21:44:29+0000"
      }
   ],
   "paging": {
      "cursors": {
         "after": "NDE2MzM3MjY4MTY=",
         "before": "MTAxNTA1ODk3NzE5MTY4MTc="
      }
   }
}
```

`[object Object]` gets returned for each item in my HTML. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly the response has an array named `data`, so you need to loop over `data.data`.

Secondly, in your example `key` will be the integer index of the iteration and `value` will be the whole object within the array. You need to access the properties of that array explicitly. Try this:

```js
// Your retrieved JSON data...
var data = {
    "data": [{
        "id": "10150589771916817",
        "name": "Mobile Uploads",
        "created_time": "2012-03-03T14:47:48+0000"
    }, {
        "id": "41633726816",
        "name": "Old pics",
        "created_time": "2008-08-18T21:44:29+0000"
    }],
    "paging": {
        "cursors": {
            "after": "NDE2MzM3MjY4MTY=",
            "before": "MTAxNTA1ODk3NzE5MTY4MTc="
        }
    }
}

// inside your AJAX request callback...
var items = [];
$.each(data.data, function (i, obj) {
    items.push('<li id="' + obj.id + '">' + obj.name + '</li>');
});

$('<ul/>', { 'class': 'my-new-list' }).append(items).appendTo('.results');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="results"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I knew I was going wrong with how I was reading the json formatting. Now i understand a lot better. Thanks!

Comment: How would I drill down another level in JSON? Say if there are images within data like: "data": [ "images": [ ] ]  ?

Comment: Inside the `each` that loops over `data.data`, have another `each` that loops over `obj.images`.

Answer (score 1):

The response contain an array named, loup thought the data array and then you can grab the key and val in a second loop.

Doing this you can access the key and val.

```js
var fbResponse = {
    "data": [{
        "id": "10150589771916817",
            "name": "Mobile Uploads",
            "created_time": "2012-03-03T14:47:48+0000"
    }, {
        "id": "41633726816",
            "name": "Old pics",
            "created_time": "2008-08-18T21:44:29+0000"
    }],
        "paging": {
        "cursors": {
            "after": "NDE2MzM3MjY4MTY=",
                "before": "MTAxNTA1ODk3NzE5MTY4MTc="
        }
    }
};


$.each(fbResponse.data, function (index, item) {
    $.each(item, function (key, val) {
        alert("Index=" + index + ", key=" + key + ", val=" + val);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery when you loop an array you get the *index* and *value*:

```
$.each([ 10, 20 ], function( index, value ) {
  alert( index + ": " + value );
});
```

output:

```
0: 10
0: 20
```

And if you iterate a collection you get *key* and *value*:

```
var obj = {
  "key 1": "value 1",
  "key 2": "value 2"
};
$.each( obj, function( key, value ) {
  alert( key + ": " + value );
})
```

output:

```
key 1: value 1
key 2: value 2
```